# Problem with Extension method: IXmlLineInfo

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

When I try to use any extension method to my class in ascx-control:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="VfmElita.Page.Stat" %>
<%=new MyTestClass().ExtMethod() %>
```

and here is the simplest method in the world:

```
namespace VfmElita.Page.Stat
{
public static class TestExtention
{
    public static string ExtMethod(this MyTestClass test)
    {
        return "Hope for result";
    }
}
}
```

(it is located in ascx.cs-file of the control

I got the following error:

> error CS0012: The type 'System.Xml.IXmlLineInfo' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.

If I replaced `ExtMethod()` with any property

```
<%= Team.GetTeamById(2).PropOk %>
```

for example, everything is fine...

Why? How can I prevent this?

P.S. It seems like question is duplicate to one of [my previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665475/problem-with-system-xml-ixmllineinfo) or [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724523/cs0012-the-type-system-xml-ixmllineinfo). But the current one is more specific and pretty detailed.

P.S. I've tried to add reference to web-site manually, VisualStuido tells that it has reference already...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is a source of such strange behavior... everything is fine with this Extension Method... answer for [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665475/problem-with-system-xml-ixmllineinfo/4719876#4719876) resolved current question too.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your project doesn't have a reference to `System.Xml` and you are using it within the real implementation of your extension method.

Comment: I've tried that. Doing that manually VS told that dll is already referenced (but I don't see how). In order to add it through the web,config - I need public token... Could you advise, how can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

make sure you're either importing the namespace of your extension method in the control header:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="My.Extension.Namespace" %>
```

or my preference, adding it to the web.config so you don't have to import all over the place

```
<pages>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="My.Extension.Namespace"/>
    </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Comment: yes, namespace was used... (I've edited question body to reflect that).

Answer (score 0):

I really like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22850466/4009972):

You can perform the extension in a function in CodeBehind.

You can use

```
<%# ExtMethod((MyTestClass)Container.DataItem) %>
```

Your CodeBehind will have:

```
protected string ExtMethod(MyTestClass test)
{
    return test.ExtMethod();
}
```

Don't forget to import the namespace of your extension module.