# Object Browser, Fully Qualified Assembly Name, and Config Files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, configuration, versioning

I needed to add a System class to my config file, and found it would not work unless given a fully qualified assembly name.  Ok, no worries, I'll simply look that up.

Uh oh.

I expected the Object Browser in Visual Studio to have that information.  That would be too obvious.  It was not there.  I started to search for how to get this information, and found [MSDN for .net 4 telling me to use Mscorcfg.msc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2exyydhb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), except MSDN also says that [Mscorcfg.msc "has been removed from .NET 4 and later versions."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bc0cxhc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)  This is not an auspicious beginning.

Of course there are answers that explain how to do it programmatically; I already know how to do that, and that isn't the point.  I don't want to write my own program just to find the publickeytoken of an assembly I want to put into my config file.

I then find an [article suggesting "sn.exe"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710935/how-do-i-find-the-publickeytoken-for-a-particular-dll) for files not in the GAC, and an [answer suggesting the gacutil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4682593/284758) for everything else.  A few others suggest using RedGate's Reflector.  Sigh.

I'm trying to figure out why such a common activity - inserting a fully qualified assembly name into a config file - requires such a "Visual Studio 6 era" hokey-pokey firedrill to get such a simple thing done.  So we come full circle: Why on EARTH does the object browser not simply provide this information?  Please tell me there is a simple VS configuration option I've missed, that explains how this is done.

To be clear, yes, I have obtained the FQAN I was seeking.  I just don't think resorting to GACUTIL.exe, after googling for a while in disbelief, should be the right answer.  What am I missing?