# asp.net web config runtimeerror

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, hosting

I searched here same problem [Asp.net - <customErrors mode="Off"/> error when trying to access working webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4363941/asp-net-customerrors-mode-off-error-when-trying-to-access-working-webpage), but when i do like it was told, i dont get any reaction same runtimeerror;

Here is my web.config

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" />
<authentication mode="None"/>
<compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<pages validateRequest="false">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems you have the compilation and authentication tag in there 2 times. Remove the duplicates.

Comment: I leave only those lines
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
  <pages validateRequest="false">
     
    </pages>
  </system.web>
and now i get "Could not load file or assembly 'Antlr3.Runtime' or one of its dependencies."

Comment: Ok, this means you are missing a dll reference in your site or missing an add assembly entry in your web.config.

Comment: how will i know what i am missing ?

Comment: Well, obviously you are missing this assembly reference "Antlr3.Runtime". I would check your project references for this dll and check if the copy local property is set to true. Alternatively you also need to check if you are adding the missing assembly in the web.config. Maybe this link can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682536/how-to-reference-assembly-from-web-config

Comment: could it be problem from hosting side ??

Comment: yes it was hosting asp.net hosting problem, i solved that , now i have this...
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Comment: ooo... Please kindly ask your hosting provider to give full permission for you and I believe that you wont face this issue again. Please make sure that your hosting provider that support full trust hosting. :)